# Rewrite Rule using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I want redirect the following URLs in different URLs. Kindly help me.

**First URL:**

http://localhost/magento2-ce/images/ **Redirect to** http://localhost/magento2-ce/

**Second URL:**

http://localhost/magento2-ce/images/9781601525871/ **Redirect to** http://localhost/magento2-ce//book/landing/detailedview?itemcode=9781601525871J

**What i did?**

I tried below solution for second URL working fine.

```
RewriteRule ^images/([0-9]+)/ http://localhost/magento2-ce/book/landing/detailedview?itemcode=$1J [R=301,NC,L]
```

But, above Rewrite Rule not working, when i apply below rule for First URL redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^images/  http://localhost/magento2-ce/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the L (last) flag from one or both rules?
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: yes, i tried but not working. Is there any conditional logic that i need to follow?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm out of ideas beyond
    RewriteRule ^images/  http://localhost/magento2-ce/ [R=301,NC]
    RewriteRule ^images/([0-9]+)/ http://localhost/magento2-ce/book/landing/detailedview?itemcode=$1J [R=301,NC,L]